# How do I modify my Char based encryption code to work with Unicode Delphi?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I'm stuck trying to make some legacy Delphi 2007 code work in Delphi XE2.

```
Function EncryptionWithPassword(Str,Pwd: AnsiString; Encode: Boolean): AnsiString;
var
  a,PwdChk,Direction,ShiftVal,PasswordDigit : Integer;
begin
  PasswordDigit := 1;
  PwdChk := 0;
  for a := 1 to Length(Pwd) do Inc(PwdChk,Ord(Pwd[a]));
  Result := PChar(Str);
  If Encode then Direction := -1 else Direction := 1;
  for a := 1 to Length(Result) do
    begin
      if Length(Pwd)=0 then
        ShiftVal := a
      else
        ShiftVal := Ord(Pwd[PasswordDigit]);
      if Odd(A) then
        Result[A] := RotateBits(Result[A],-Direction*(ShiftVal+PwdChk))
      else
        Result[A] := RotateBits(Result[A],Direction*(ShiftVal+PwdChk));
      inc(PasswordDigit);
      if PasswordDigit > Length(Pwd) then PasswordDigit := 1;
    end;

end;

Function RotateBits(C: Char; Bits: Integer): Char;
var
  SI : Word; 
begin 
  Bits := Bits mod 8; 
  // Are we shifting left? 
  if Bits < 0 then 
    begin 
      // Put the data on the right half of a Word (2 bytes) 
      SI := MakeWord(Byte(C),0); 
      // Now shift it left the appropriate number of bits 
      SI := SI shl Abs(Bits);
    end
  else
    begin
      // Put the data on the left half of a Word (2 bytes)
      SI := MakeWord(0,Byte(C));
      // Now shift it right the appropriate number of bits
      SI := SI shr Abs(Bits);
    end;
  // Now OR the two halves together
  SI := Lo(SI) or Hi(SI);
  Result := Chr(SI);
end;
```

No matter what I try - the function corrupts the string. After I've applied the AnsiString cheat, I've tried using arrays of chars, etc, nothing works. Please if anyone with some insight can assist and explain - I'm at my wits end and is delaying a huge project.

Comment: What is this code? Does this code do what you want on D2007? Or is this your attempt at a port? What is the expected output of the program. How does it fail.

Comment: Both - it's my attempted port, but it works find in D2007, but corrupts the strings while converting. It's based on a sample off the web (can only find it here now: http://www.hur.cn/special/delphiProgram/06051.htm). EncryptionWithPassword uses RotateBits.

Comment: Did you read up on the Unicode changes at all? It's just that the use of `Char` sticks out like a sore thumb. I really suggest that you take some time out and read Marco's whitepaper. It will help you finish the port quicker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change Char to AnsiChar and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks @TLama!! Mind posting so I can mark it as the answer? I've already implemented Nick's suggestion in the above but missed the PAnsiChar.

Comment: First rule of encryption is, treat everything as bytes. Stay the hell away from string representations. Check my old post on this topic: http://www.cromis.net/blog/2009/11/how-to-correctly-handle-cryptography-in-ansi-and-unicode-flavor/

Comment: I just use it on non-critical stuff that needs to be strings.

Comment: Man, Hein, did you read NONE of the Unicode transition documentation that is ALL over the delphi world?  CHAR in unicode delphi is more than 1 byte in size. Seriously.

Comment: @WarrenP Of course I did, I converted all the chars to AnsiChars and strings to AnsiStrings, but didn't realise there was a PAnsiChar, so maybe I did not read far enough into the 40 page whitepaper :/

Comment: The Code above clearly shows you did not convert all Char to AnsiChar. :-)